# using JOIN, how do I get the max numOfStars for each level for this table?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

Here is the table with some data

```
+-----+-------+--------+-----------+------------+-------+------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| id  | level | userId | numOfSecs | numOfStars | score | mostRecent | creationTime        | allLevelsFinished |
+-----+-------+--------+-----------+------------+-------+------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| 113 |     1 | 21     |        12 |          3 |  1000 |          1 | 2017-11-14 17:39:06 |                 0 |
| 114 |    10 | 21     |        25 |          3 |  1000 |          1 | 2017-11-14 17:41:21 |                 0 |
| 115 |     5 | 21     |        16 |          3 |  1000 |          1 | 2017-11-14 18:37:40 |                 0 |
| 119 |     1 | 23     |       194 |          1 |   200 |          0 | 2017-11-15 13:21:50 |                 0 |
| 120 |     1 | 23     |       121 |          1 |   444 |          0 | 2017-11-15 13:16:01 |                 0 |
| 121 |     1 | 23     |       221 |          3 |   333 |          0 | 2017-11-15 18:14:48 |                 0 |
| 122 |     1 | 23     |       343 |          2 |   555 |          0 | 2017-11-15 13:19:54 |                 0 |
| 123 |     1 | 23     |       355 |          1 |   555 |          1 | 2017-11-15 13:21:19 |                 0 |
| 124 |     2 | 23     |       333 |          1 |   333 |          0 | 2017-11-15 15:25:59 |                 0 |
| 125 |     2 | 23     |       444 |          2 |   444 |          0 | 2017-11-15 15:26:26 |                 0 |
| 126 |     2 | 23     |       222 |          2 |  2222 |          0 | 2017-11-15 15:26:59 |                 0 |
| 127 |     2 | 23     |        44 |          1 |   444 |          1 | 2017-11-15 15:27:24 |                 0 |
+-----+-------+--------+-----------+------------+-------+------------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

I'm aware that I could use

```
SELECT id, userId, numOfSecs, level, max(numOfStars) 
WHERE userId=23 
GROUP BY level
```

However, I'm interested in becoming more familiar with JOIN, even though JOIN is typically used with 2 or more tables.  What I would like to do with my query is select all the rows where userId=23 and then do a second query on the results of the first query to find the max number of stars for each level listed.  From the research I've done, a left inner join could do the job, but I'm having difficulty with aliases using a single table.

Comment: There's no such thing as "left inner join". "left" and "right" are always outer joins.

Comment: Your awareness is off. That query is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the same using `left join` with same table but some tweaks in `on` clause to pick the highest numOfStars row

```
select a.*
from demo a
left join demo b
       on a.userId = b.userId
       and a.level = b.level
       and case when a.numOfStars = b.numOfStars
                then a.score < b.score
                else a.numOfStars < b.numOfStars
                end
where b.id is null
and a.userId = 23
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65217e/7)

> Note i have added a `case` clause for a scenario if user id, level and numOfStars are equal then it will pick the row on basis of highest score

Comment: Old school. Nice.